# HTTPS fails to authorize with JWT. No Authorization header is present in the request

Tags: authentication, yii2, http-headers, jwt

I've got an API server based on Yii2 framework. It uses authentication by means of JSON web token. It works fine when I use http, there is an Authorization header provided. To check if the header is present I've made a test method that returns the token.

```php
public function actionTest(){
    return Yii::$app->request->getHeaders()->get('Authorization');
}
```

When I make a request (from Postman) over http, the result is as follows

> "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvc29mdG1hZXN0cmkuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTcxOTg0NjMzLCJleHAiOjE1NzI1ODk0MzMsInVpZCI6MTAwLCJuYmYiOjE1NzE5ODQ2MzMsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJwYXNzX2hhc2giOiIkUCRCdUtCTmNuUkxRWDdBSFFVMThrQ1ZRYjQxUXZicGIwIn19fQ.zbGk8blRIVRz6h4RLwT7wavH1jFv1cajlKwXYuzAZDE"

But once I do the same over https, it returns null.
I also have an .htaccess file with the following content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The API routes that don't require authentication work just fine over https, so it's definitely not a certificate problem or something related.

What am I missing here? Maybe there must be something else added to the htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved the problem by changing 
this

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

to this

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

I understand that the second version sets an environment variable and the first one doesn't, but I have no idea why the first version didn't work with https but worked with http. So I'd be grateful if someone could explain in to me